# Unable to save an RDD[String] as a text file using saveAsTextFile

Tags: scala, classnotfoundexception, apache-spark-1.4

When I try to write my RDD to a text file on HDFS as shown below, I am getting an error.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/user/hadoop/dxld801/test.txt")
val filtered = rdd.map({line=> line.replace("\\N","NULL")})
filtered.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:///user/hadoop/dxld801/test.txt")
```

**Error:**

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter not found

I am running all the above in a **spark-shell** and my spark **version** is **1.4.0**

This is the command I am using to launch the shell 
`$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0 --jars /home/hadoop/lib/native/hadoop-lzo-0.4.14.jar`

I have tried googling to get where this class “`DirectFileOutputCommitter`” is available, but looks like this class doesn’t exist at all in this world.

**Trace:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter not found
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1927)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getOutputCommitter(JobConf.java:722)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:983)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:965)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:965)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:109)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:965)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:897)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:897)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:897)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:109)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:896)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1400)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1379)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1379)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:109)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1379)
>         at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:26)
>         at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:31)
>         at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
>         at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)
>         at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
>         at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
>         at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
>         at $iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
>         at <init>(<console>:45)
>         at .<init>(<console>:49)
>         at .<clinit>(<console>)
>         at .<init>(<console>:7)
>         at .<clinit>(<console>)
>         at $print(<console>)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>         at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
>         at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter not found
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1895)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1919)
>         ... 68 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter not found
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1801)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1893)
>         ... 69 more
```

Could anyone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path to save location `"hdfs:///user/hadoop/dxld801/test.txt"` is wrong. It should be: `"/user/hadoop/dxld801/test.txt"` or `"hdfs://HOSTNAME:PORT/user/hadoop/dxld801/test.txt"`

Also fix the line:
`rdd.map({line=> line.replace("\\N","NULL")})`
to
`rdd.map{line=> line.replace("\\N","NULL")}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ipoteka, 

I have tried in all the ways suggested above, still no luck. 

`hdfs://HOSTNAME:9101/user/hadoop/test/test_out.txt
and
/user/hadoop/test/test_out.txt`

Comment: @RavitejSomayajula Also fix the line: `rdd.map({line=> line.replace("\\N","NULL")})`  - i edited my answer.

Comment: It didn't work, @ipoteka.

Possibly, we should try to identify why the shell is not able to find `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter` despite running on a hadoop environment.

Comment: The problem is likely in your incorrect syntax. Or maybe you are reading not from text file or maybe you write the expression wrong again. The spark-shell error message is not usefull in these situations, do not pay much attention to it. Best luck!